# change DropdownList Datasource Dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `dropDownlist` that have tow `Datasource` with names `Datasource1`,`Datasource2`. 
when the page_Load accrued the datasource1 is assigned to `Dropdownlist`. I have a button on page that i want when i clicked on button, Datasource2 assign to `Dropdownlist` in `button click event` i wrote this:

```
Ddl_Num.DataSource = SqlDataSource8;
      Ddl_Num.DataBind();
```

but it doesn't changed.
how can i do that?

Comment: When you assigned datasource1 to Dropdownlist, did you do it inside if(!IsPostback) ?

Answer (score 2):

Try use !isPostBack with combination of Session

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!isPostBack || Session["DataSource"] = null)        
    {
         Ddl_Num.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;//DataSource1
         Ddl_Num.DataBind(); 
    }
}

protected void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Ddl_Num.DataSource = SqlDataSource2;//DataSource2
    Ddl_Num.DataBind();

    Session["ChangeDataSource"] = true; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

set `AutoPostBack="True"`.Eg.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" ></asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: A button is clicked to change the datasource. Nothing mentioned about the dropdownlist having to do anything.

Comment: i set the auto postback true it true;

Answer (score 1):

You've to populate Dasource2. This can be done when you click the button or with global declaration of datasource in some where else in your page(may be page load event). Better you write the code for it in your button_click event.Set autopostback=true for your button. Then clear the dropdownlist first and then bind the datasource to your dropdownlist.Set runat="server" and autopostback="true" for both dropdownlist and button. When are you populating your datasource2 ? In which event?

Comment: can you check whether the datasource2 is being populated or not properly?

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing anything in your PreRender event handler?

Comment: Could you please share how you are binding the first data source???
Are you using any try catch blocks/ dynamic controls?